# System command error code of 126

Tags: php, ffmpeg, system

Please, I am trying to convert an mpg file to flv with ffmpeg. I am using the php system() command to execute it. However, I get an error code of 126. Any idea of what that means? Here is my code:
 `system($ffmpegPath. " -i ". $srcFile. " -b 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 1835k ". $destFile, $cmd_status)`

Thanks. I discovered I was referring to the wrong ffmpeg binary. However, now that I am pointing to the right binary, I get an error of 127. Any help?

Comment: Can ffmpeg encode the same file if you run the command from the command line?

Comment: @Joachim, Yes it can. However, I am running it now on a centos server using php script. The configurations are all ok

Comment: Seems you don't have a library required to run the process, or the library can not be found in the system's `path`.

Comment: When you say I don't have the library, what actually do you mean? what other library is required besides the ones that are usually installed alongside the ffmpeg?

Comment: I can't guess this. You should run `ldd` against ffmpeg and make sure all listed libraries are accessible from the user account under which php runs.

Answer (score 5):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> If a command is found but is not  executable,
>          the return status is 126.

Make sure that you can execute the given binary.